# Message from debugger: Terminated due to Memory Pressure in TableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have created the table view using custom nib file in which i have add two images to create view like grid. When i add around 50 rows the app show me the message "memory warning" and then it will crash and Xcode show me the error "Message from debugger: Terminated due to Memory Pressure". I am testing app in iPhone 4s. it also crashes in iPhone 6. I am also using SDWebimage library for loading images. but even after comment the code of set images in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method it crashes. Here is my code

```
 SingleEventTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SingleEventTableViewCell"];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"cell allocated");

    cell = [[SingleEventTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SingleEventTableViewCell"];
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SingleEventTableViewCell"
                                                 owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how can I check memory leakage or something to resolve this issue.

Comment: Use the Instruments tool that comes with Xcode.  It has an Allocations template that will show what's using memory.

Comment: Are you aware of that the first allocation is useless? You need to load the nib in the initialiser of the class.

Comment: EDUsta, Can you please explain little more. i can't understand your point.